# Include different scripts and styles for two separate custom headers?

Tags: custom-header

I would like to have 2 different header files that I can use depending on which section of the website I am on. For example, display custom header#1 if not logged in, and display custom header#2 if logged in. I want to enqueue different scripts and styles on each of the header files using `functions.php`. The problem is that I need to call `wp_head()` on each of the header files, which means that they will load the same scripts and styles. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Check whatever conditions you want to enqueue specific scripts on within your enqueue function.

```
function wpd_enqueue_scripts() {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/logged-in.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/not-logged-in.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpd_enqueue_scripts' );
```